# computer lab with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this assignment with managing computer labs. Specifically, there are 4 labs, each has a different number of computers. Hence, I want to create a 2D array with pointers, but after trying different stuff, I count on you for this error (please!!!). Below is a part of my programme, up to where the annoying bug comes up.

I got a run-time error after 1 run (terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::bad_array_new_length what(): std::bad_array_new_length`) when I leave the line with comment //PROBLEM HERE as such.

Add a & in front of lab room, the compiler gave me the error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

Newbie in C++, first time with pointers, I'd appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Global variables

const int SIZE = 4;
typedef int* Stations;
Stations *labroom;

//Function declaration:

void numberOfComputers();//Receive number of computers in each lab
int menu();//Display menu options for users
void menu_processor(int option);//process user's option

int main()
{
    numberOfComputers();
    menu();
    menu_processor(menu());
    return 0;
}

void numberOfComputers ()
{   char ans;
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of computer stations in lab "<<i+1<<": ";
        do
        {
            cin.get(ans);
        } while (ans!='\n');
        labroom [i] = new int [ans-'0'];//PROBLEM HERE
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it seems that you never have allocated any memory for your `labroom` Array.

Comment: Have a look at what [causes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length) that error, too, and check what the values of `ans` and `ans-'0'` are.

Comment: First things first, you need to allocate memory for `labroom`. 2) What's happening here `labroom [i] = new int [ans-'0'];`? After the `do-while` loop `ans` will always be `\n`.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: you are writing in C++ so why don't you use containers such as `std::vector`?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks all for helping. By allocating memory, you mean giving a fixed size for that array? Like Stations *labroom [4][7] while I can still modify 7 by other values after I have input for ans? Though it would consume unnecessary memories as (ans-'0') might just give 5 for example.

I already checked the values for ans and ans - '0' using cout, everything works perfectly for my loop without that line where I added the comment
#Michael: I want to practice with pointers. I'm sorry I'm very inexperienced in all this so practicing will get me there at some point :)

Comment: @J.Doe You have to assign `labroom` some value before you attempt to use its value. Doing `labroom[i]` asks for the i'th element in the thing that `labroom` points to. So you can't do that until it points to something. Until `labroom` points to something, the i'th element of what `labroom` points to isn't meaningful, so you can't assign it the value that `new` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not c++ code, it's just (ugly) C.

In C++ we have `array` for static arrays and `vector` for dynamic arrays.

First of all, choose the name of your variables or function in a smart way: prefer `getNumberOfComputersFromUser` instead of `numberOfComputers`. What `numberOfComputers` means? A function name must describe what it is doing.

Here a simplified snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using Station = int;
using LabRooms = array<vector<Station>, 4>;

LabRooms getNumberOfComputersFromUser()
{
    LabRooms labRooms;
    int roomIndex = 0;
    for(auto& computersInLab : labRooms)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of computer stations in lab " << ++roomIndex << ": ";

        auto computerCount = 0;
        cin >> computerCount;
        computersInLab.resize(computerCount);
    }
    return labRooms;
}
```

## Explain

`array` requires two template arguments: the type and the size. Elements are statically allocated, no need to new because we already know how many rooms we have. The list of computers in each room is not know so we use `vector` that can dynamically increase or decrease.

`using LabRooms = array<vector<Station>, 4>;` it's the same of `typedef array<vector<Station>, 4> LabRooms` but it's clearer I think

`for( auto& computersInLab : labRooms)` iterate over `labRooms` and get a reference to its elements (in this case a reference to a `vector` of `Station`. This is the same of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < labRooms.size(); ++i)
{
    auto& computersInLab = labRooms[i];
    ...
}
```

`computersInLab.resize(computerCount);` resize the list of computers with the value specified from the user.

Now, `labRooms` is an array of 4 elements, each element is a list of `Station`.

Comment: `auto computerCount;` ? don't you mean `int computerCount;`?

Comment: @Caleth you right i wanted write `auto computerCount = 0;`. I've fixed it now.